# How is the Overlap Distribution Sampled for Spin Glasses Computationally

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, spin-models

To study the phase transition of spin glasses, a commonly used order parameter is the Binder's parameter, defined as the 4th order cumulant of the overlap distribution $P_J(q)$, where $q$ is defined as the spin overlap of two replicas sampled from the Gibbs measure. I'm interested in only statistics from a single spin glass realization, so there is no quenched averages anywhere.

My question is in computer simulations, how is the statistics of $q$ actually sampled. Naively, I would think one can run an MCMC chain for some time until the glass is believed to reach equilibrium, and then continue to run the chain to get some equilibrium samples of the glass, say $10000$ samples. Now, to sample $q$, do I simply extract pairs from the $10000$ samples to get the statistics of $q$? This would seem terribly inefficient memory wise, because it involves saving $10000$ samples, and there may be problems with auto-correlation.

Another way I'm thinking this would work is to initialize different replicas and run them independently. Then at each iteration, simply extract the $q$ statistics between the replicas, so that the spin configurations of each iteration need not be saved. This is perhaps more efficient. Is this what is actually done in practice? Some reference to the state-of-the-art computational methods for obtaining efficient overlap statistics would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know about spin glasses specifically, but in Bayesian parameter estimation one does in fact run an MCMC until it "burns in" (reached a state where it is fairly drawing samples from the posterior). There is then a post processing step involving "thinning" the chains to remove correlated samples.

Comment: @Andrew That's sort of what I have in mind as well. Do you have a reference to the "thinning" procedure you mentioned?

Comment: There are a few cross-validation posts about this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119879/how-to-interpret-autocorrelation-plot-in-mcmc, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442714/why-does-thinning-work-in-bayesian-inference. There is also a paper by Link and Eaton that actually recommends not thinning except in special situations: https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2011.00131.x. YMMV; I work in gravitational wave data analysis where thinning is done regularly, see eg after Eq 23 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7215.pdf.